# Convert index array in associative array php for loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have following array:

```
$all_items = Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => bcd
    [2] => cde
    [3] => def
    [4] => efg
)
```

I would like to turn this array into an associative array like below.

```
array(
        array('A'=>abc, 'position'=>0), 
        array('A'=>bcd, 'position'=>1),
        array('A'=>cde, 'position'=>2),
        array('A'=>abc, 'position'=>3), 
        array('A'=>bcd, 'position'=>4)
),
```

So far I have tried many different method with no luck. Here is my code.

```
$k = 0;
  foreach($all_items as $item) {
    $all_items[$key]['src'] =$item;
    $all_items[$key]['position']=i;
    $k++;
  };
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward, try this way:

```
<?php
$items = array();
foreach($all_items as $k=>$v) {
  $items[] = array(
    'A' => $v,
    'position' => $k
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

(Here I just loop through the array with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and return a new array for each value)

```
<?php

    $all_items = ["abc", "bcd", "cde", "def", "efg"];

    $result = array_map(function($v, $k){
        return ["A" => $v, "position" => $k];
    }, $all_items, array_keys($all_items));

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => abc
            [position] => 0
        )
    //...

    [4] => Array
        (
            [A] => efg
            [position] => 4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
$newArr = array_map('buildArr', $all_items, array_keys($all_items));

function buildArr($data, $key) {
   $result = array('A' => $data, 'position' => $key);
   return $result;
}
var_dump($newArr);
```